# Put image in front and center of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, overlay

I have seen many variations of this question, but have not found any desirable answer.

I would like to put center an image in front of a `div`.

If I have a `div` that is loading ajax content, I will (using `css`, `jquery`, however) put an image in front of the `div` that is loading, and then remove it when the `div` is done loading. Now, although that is the situation, the solution should not be constrained to this specific situation. Hopefully I (and anyone else) will be able to do this whenever they need to overly an image on a `div`.

That is the salient point. I do not want to grey out the whole screen and put the image in the center of the window, or put it below, or to the side, or at an absolute position. Those things are relatively simple. I want the image smack-dab in the middle of the given `div`, wherever that `div` may happen to be.

NOTE: I would prefer solutions that do not require an additional `jquery` plugin. I would like to use as little code as possible to get the job done.

Comment: Is the div of fixed size? Otherwise if it hasn't loaded, it wouldn't have a height and width determined yet.

Comment: You could make a div within the loading div, then set the property `margin:auto auto;`.  When AJAX is done loading, have it use jQuery to set the div's display to `display:none;`

Comment: The div's current height and width should be used. Like I said, don't get bogged down in the specifics of using ajax. Basically there is just a div that needs an image overlaid in the center.
@RyanSparks Could you by any chance be more specific than that?

Answer (score 0):

Place the image where you like it with CSS. If the image never changes size, this could work:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -#px (where # is half the width of the image);
    margin-top: -#px (where # is half the width of the image);
}
```

And then do something like this to detect when the page is loaded and hide the div. You could also use .remove() if you like.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $(".mydiv").hide();
});
```

To target a specific item and detect if it's loaded, do $(".mydiv").load(function() {});

It should be noted that there are a myriad of other ways to center an image in the middle of a div. You could do `width: 100%; height: 100%;` with `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 1;` and then put the image as a `background: url('myimage.png') no-repeat scroll center center transparent;`.

You can do that with a :before or :after pseudo-element as well, that way you don't even need to add anything to the HTML.

You could also set and  tag at the bottom of the div and then the image as `display: block;` and `margin: auto auto;`, etc.